Prevent notifications from Google Home App on other Google accounts on the same device
I have 2 Google accounts activated on my Pixel 8a. I have Google Home notifications turned on from my primary Google account.
How do I disable Google Home notifications for a second Google account on the same device (Pixel 8a)?

You don't. Notifications are per app, not per account.
